# create dynamic elements and move others within them

Tags: javascript, jquery

basically I have several inputs in the DOM, I need to create the same amount of divs according to the inputs, once created, move each input within the created element, I'm using jquery for this, example:

```
    <!-- first state: without inserting anything -->
    <div class="container">
        <input type="example-element">
        <input type="example-element">
        <input type="example-element">
    </div>

    <!-- second: inserting the dynamic elements -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="dinamic-element"> </div>
        <div class="dinamic-element"> </div>
        <div class="dinamic-element"> </div>

        <input type="example-element">
        <input type="example-element">
        <input type="example-element">
    </div>

    <!-- result: this is what I try to do -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="dinamic-element">
            <input type="example-element">
        </div>
        <div class="dinamic-element">
            <input type="example-element">
        </div>
        <div class="dinamic-element">
            <input type="example-element">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
// select all <input> elements within elements
// having a class of 'container':
$('.container input')
  // wrapping each of those elements individually
  // with the supplied HTML:
  .wrap('<div class="dynamic"></div>');
```

```js
$('.container input').wrap('<div class="dynamic"></div>');
```

```css
.dynamic {
  border: 1px solid #f90;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="example-element">
  <input type="example-element">
  <input type="example-element">
</div>
```

In plain – albeit ES6 – JavaScript:

```
// creating a <div> element:
let div = document.createElement('div'),

  // initialising an element to hold clones
  // of that created <div>:
  clone;

// adding the 'dynamic' class-name, via the
// HTMLElement.classList API, to the created
// <div>:
div.classList.add('dynamic');

// using Array.from() to convert the result of
// the document.querySelectorAll() method into
// an Array, in order to use Array methods:
Array.from(

  // finding all <input> elements that are contained
  // within element(s) with a class of 'container':
  document.querySelectorAll('.container input')

// iterating over the Array of elements using
// Array.prototype.forEach(), and an anonymous
// Arrow function:
).forEach(

  // input is a reference to the current <input>
  // element of the Array of <input> elements over
  // which we're iterating:
  input => {

    // here we clone the created <div> element, and
    // assign that clone the 'clone' variable:
    clone = div.cloneNode();

    // replacing the input node with the cloned <div>:
    input.replaceWith(clone);

    // appending the input node to the cloned <div>:
    clone.appendChild(input);
  }
);
```

```js
let div = document.createElement('div'),
  clone;
div.classList.add('dynamic');
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.container input')).forEach(
  input => {
    clone = div.cloneNode();
    input.replaceWith(clone);
    clone.appendChild(input);
  }
);
```

```css
.dynamic {
  border: 1px solid #f90;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="example-element">
  <input type="example-element">
  <input type="example-element">
</div>
```

And, finally, in plain – ES5 – JavaScript:

```
let div = document.createElement('div'),
  clone;
div.classList.add('dynamic');

// here we use Function.prototype.call() to apply
// the Array.prototype.slice() to the HTMLCollection
// returned by document.querySelectorAll(), which
// is an older means of converting an Array-like
// Object into an Array:
Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.container input')
).forEach(function(input) {
  // here we use a traditional anonymous function declaration
  // rather than using the aArrow function, but it behaves
  // identically as above:
  clone = div.cloneNode();
  input.replaceWith(clone);
  clone.appendChild(input);
});
```

```js
let div = document.createElement('div'),
  clone;
div.classList.add('dynamic');
Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.container input')
).forEach(function(input) {
  clone = div.cloneNode();
  input.replaceWith(clone);
  clone.appendChild(input);
});
```

```css
.dynamic {
  border: 1px solid #f90;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="example-element">
  <input type="example-element">
  <input type="example-element">
</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [JavaScript Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`ChildNode.replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith).
  - [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
- jQuery:

  - [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Comment: omg, you saved me hours thinking about this friend, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using jQuery

```
$( "input.example-element").wrap("<div class='dinamic-element'></div>");
```